# What's the best field type and data usage to accelerate searches?

Tags: database, performance, search, indexing

I have a question about equivalent search result, that can occur on different fields.

Let's say I record the logical deletion state of records with 3 fields like :

- *Boolean* Deleted
- *Date* DeleteDate
- *String* DeleteUserName

The goal of the query is to avoid having deleted records into my selection.
So I can search the first field with only 2 values (True/False), or on the deletion date : a lot of different values, or on the username, different values but not a lot.

What will give the best search result time, regarding the index usage ?

Comment: What DBMS are you using. What indexes are available? Are you asking what indexes to create? What is the ration from updates to your data to queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'deleted' = 0`

(In that format) then it would be the fastest:  The others don't **search** faster or slower, however, there is less overhead required to compare Bools than to compare Strings/Dates. (Usually, aspects of different systems change, some Bools are stored as 8-bit, and not optimized per equality testing)

Answer (score 0):

What queries do you intend to exeute? Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `deleted`=0
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `deleted_date` IS NULL
```

They should be about the same if `deleted` and `deleted_date` are indexed.